# Is a bad NFS mount preventing a clean boot?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount, boot, fstab

I'm on Ubuntu server (I think it's 12.04, but not positive) and I basically ran into this problem here [Unmount a nfs mount where the nfs server has disappeared](https://serverfault.com/questions/56588/unmount-a-nfs-mount-where-the-nfs-server-has-disappeared)

The `umount` command didn't work, so I tried to just use the ol' reboot. Now the machine gets an error when booting:

```
FS-Cache:netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
<two minutes later>
init: udevtrigger post-stop process (345) terminated with status 1
```

I tried booting in recovery mode so I could just comment out the bad NFS mount in my `/etc/fstab` file, but I wasn't able to write the changes.

I basically just want to get the machine booting properly again so that I can erase the bad mount point, either order is fine.

What are my options here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got into recovery mode and ran `mount -o remount,rw /` which allowed me to get rid of my bad NFS mounts in `/etc/fstab` (and I prevented further issues by adding the `intr` option to the NFS entries), but then my boot (in non-recovery) seemingly got worse -- I got no output on the screen after selecting normal boot from the GRUB menu!

I then added `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` boot option list and everything worked.

I have no idea how those two were related, but that's what fixed the issue.

Comment: So you really did exactly what @DanilaLadner recommended. Why post your own answer with the same content instead of just accepting his answer?

Comment: Because there was additional information

Comment: He pointed you in the right direction. If there was additional info, edit his answer and include it and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this in rescue mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and then modify your /etc/fstab.

Or boot LiveCD and mount / somewhere with "rw".

Comment: So I got into recovery mode and ran mount -o remount,rw / which allowed me to get rid of my bad NFS mounts in /etc/fstab, but now my boot (in non-recovery) has seemingly gotten worse -- I get no output on the screen after selecting normal boot from the GRUB menu!

Comment: It has nothing to do with you removing NSF record with /etc/fstab. use alt + ctl to switch tty to see what comes on boot to stdout to see any boot errors.